# bootstrapping for quantifying classification error

Tags: classification, bootstrap, error

I have a dataset with ~ 1 million points. Each of them has an `assigned label` belonging to `{0,1}`. However, not all of the points are correctly labeled. I want to quantify the error in the labelings. The only way I can validate the correctness of the `assigned labels` is by hand. So my plan, is to manually re-label a small set (say 1000 samples from my dataset). Lets call these `manual labels` and they will be my source of truth.

Then, I want use the information from the `assigned labels` and `manual labels` and bootstrapping methods to estimate the error in the labels.

I have data points `S = {x_1, ... , x_n}` which have `assigned labels {a_1, ..., a_n}` and `manual labels {m_1, ... , m_n}`. Let the mean classification error be `S_m := (y_1 + … + y_n)/x` where `y_m = abs(a_m - m_n)`.

I want to get a confidence interval for the percentage error in classification in my population. This is where I am not sure if I am doing the right thing -

Can I sample with replacement `n` points from `S`. If I do this `p` times and get errors `S_1, ... S_p` sorted in increasing order for the resampled samples, can I calculate the confidence interval for the classification error of the population like so:

The `100(1-2/p)` % confidence interval for the classification error = `(S_m - d_1,S_m  - d_p)`.
where `d_k = (S_k -  Sbar) for k in {1,..,p}`

I followed the reasoning for calculating confidence intervals directly from here https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2014/readings/MIT18_05S14_Reading24.pdf

Is my calculation and adopted methodology correct?

Comment: Are you aware of Brad Efron's paper Bootstrap Methods Improvement on Cross-Validation (1983) JASA?

Answer (score 2):

The actual title of the paper is "Estimating the error rate of a prediction rule: Improvements on Cross-Validation" by Brad Efron, Journal of the American Statistical Association (1983). He introduced the 632 estimator which was better than Lachenbruch's leave-one-out method.  Efron did simulations for multivariate Gaussian distributions to show that his estimator was superior. It was followed in later years by simulations I did on non-Gaussian distributions to show that it was still superior.  Efron and Tibshirani later modified it to what they called 632+.

Comment: @Micheal Thanks for the reference! I also saw this paper (that you mentioned) https://www.jstor.org/stable/2965703?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents that I found useful

Comment: @Micheal The .632 and .632+ methods apparently have lower variance than the hold-out and cross-validation methods. But can the variance be 'quantified' for the bootstrap methods? I did not find such thing in the papers. Or can some sort of confidence interval be obtained for the estimated parameter? One more question I had was, is one of these methods (hold out, cross validation, bootstrapping) or some other method particularly suited for small training sets (since its manual work for me). Thanks so much!

Comment: There are a variety of bootstrap approaches to obtain confidence intervals. Perhaps you are aware of percentile, BC and BCa.

Comment: The link that you gave is the 1997 paper by Efron and Tibshirani.  After 14 years of research on classification problems they came up with this improvement.